# apache two way ssl auth with kerberos

Tags: linux, apache, authentication, ssl, kerberos

I am trying to configure apache to authenticate first via a two-way SSL handshake and then the mod_auth_kerberos kicks in, which is all working fine..backend is freeIPA.

however i want to restrict the user to SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN and not authenticate to any other valid kerberos user

this is the virtualhost configs,

```
LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/mod_auth_kerb.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin web01.server.hostingprovider.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName myserver.name
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/server-cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/private/server-key.pem

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/cacert.pem

    LogLevel debug
    DumpIOInput On
    DumpIOOutput On
    ScriptAlias /application /var/www/app.cgi
    ErrorLog "logs/app01-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/app01-access_log" common

    <Location />
      SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
      AuthType Kerberos
      AuthName "Kerberos Login"
      KrbMethodNegotiate On
      KrbMethodK5Passwd On
      KrbAuthRealms MYREALM.COM
      Krb5KeyTab /etc/security/keytabs/spnego.service.keytab
      require valid-user
    </Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried this with SSLRequire and this works fine for user "krisdigitx", but it also allows other kerberos users to authenticate with the same certificate.

```
SSLRequire (%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "krisdigitx")
```

1. How can I create a DB i.e

SSLRequire (%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "from some DB")

should match to a user in DB and then allow access?

2. How can I match the user verified in first step and allow only him to be passed for kerberos authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the general guide to [Web App Authentication](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Web_App_Authentication) with FreeIPA.  What you are trying to do is convoluted (see answers below) and there are better ways to restrict access to particular users or groups, e.g. using HBAC rules and **mod_authnz_pam**.

Now, onto the answers:

1. According to the [`SSLRequire documentation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) only literals, mod_ssl [environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) and the `file` expansion function can be used in the match expression.  It is almost impossible to achieve what you want (you could hypothetically use FUSE or similar technology to present the result of a database query as a file).
2. If the `SSLRequire` directive is not matched access will be refused, therefore no additional processing is required to restrict Kerberos authentication to only the matched user(s).